# Xamarin.Forms HorizontalTextAlignment not working on iOS

Tags: c#, user-interface, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, label

Here is the issue I've been busting my head over for the better part of a day - I've got a very simple page that is comprised of a StackLayout with two elements inside it - an SVG image(FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms) and a Label. The Label needs to have its text aligned to the right - that's just how the design is. On Android I have no issue - HorizontalTextAlignment="End" works right away. On iOS however, it does not. The text is there, the space is there - I've checked by setting the BackgroundColor of the Label - but the text is not aligned to the right. Here are some code snippets below of the XAML:

```
<StackLayout Spacing="0"
             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
             Orientation="Vertical"
             Margin="50">
    <svgImageLib:SvgCachedImage x:Name="Logo"
                                Source="logo.svg"
                                VerticalOptions="Start"
                                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                AutomationId="Login"
                                WidthRequest="160" />
    <Label VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
           HorizontalOptions="End"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
           LineBreakMode="WordWrap">
        <Label.FormattedText>
            <FormattedString>
                <Span Text="SOME VERY BIG APPLICATION TEXT"
                      FontAttributes="Bold"
                      TextColor="White">
                    <Span.LineHeight>
                        <OnPlatform Android="2.4"
                                    iOS="0.8" />
                    </Span.LineHeight>
                    <Span.FontSize>
                        <OnPlatform Android="45"
                                    iOS="40" />
                    </Span.FontSize>
                </Span>
            </FormattedString>
        </Label.FormattedText>
    </Label>
</StackLayout>
```

Again, this works fine on Android, on iOS it fails. I have not tested on an actual device - only in the Simulator. I'm open to suggestions if anybody has any idea why this is not working only on iOS. Also, if it matters, Center also does not work there.

Comment: It's seems to be a bug in the latest version, manually setting the alignment to right in renderer is working

Comment: What versions are you using? It seems weird form your code. I can't find the `LineHeight` property in the Span class. And when we want to set the FontSize on each platform we should use `<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Android="45" iOS="40"/>`.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Xamarin.Forms - 3.2.0.871581. And the OnPlatform call is working fine like I've set it, no need to explicitly set the TypeArguments in this case.